# Capture and print entire exception and assertion error

Tags: python-3.x, try-catch, jupyter-lab

I am using `JupyterLab` and `Pyton 3`. I have an assertion that is not satisfied, which creates an error. When I run the cell with the error, I get the following, with details about where in my code this happened:

[image]

However, this also stops the notebook from running subsequent cells. If instead use `try` and `except` to capture the error and print it, I don't get as much detail about the error, but the subsequent cells continue to run:

[image]

How do I still print the more extended information after the error, and also continue to run subsequent cells of code in the notebook? I prefer to not use features of JupyterLab, such as tags or extensions to continue running subsequent cells, if possible. Or, are those extra details being generated by JupyterLab?